# More efficient method for creating a string from a single letter of a word

Tags: java

Currently my program use multiple if{} loops to create a new string from a single letter from a name. The program looks something like this:

```
public static String cool(String S) {
     int c = s.charAt(0);
     String adj = "";
     if (c==97) {
         adj += "Awesome";
         return adj;
     }

     else if(c==98) {
         adj += "Badass";
         return adj;
     }
     ...

     else {
         adj+= "Invalid Character, please try again";
         return adj;
     }
}
```

and i was made aware that you could use arrays for this problem, but seeing as my class has not learned this yet, but I wanted to use it in a personal program, I was wondering what the most efficient method for this would be.

Thank you so much!

EDIT: I forgot to add the fact that I'm using this code for all 26 letters via ASCII values in case that ellipsis in the middle of the code wasn't clear.

EDIT 2: The question is asking for the most time efficient method to type out, not for the computer necessarily

Edit 3: Yep, im a dumbass lol, I didn't name my method lmao

Comment: You forgot to name your function

Comment: Why are you using `+=`? `adj ` is always empty.

Comment: One option is to use *HashMap* to associate values with 97, 98, and other keys

Comment: "most time efficient method to type out": Programming is a form of expository writing. Please consider both the writer's and the reader's experience. Yes, usually reasonably short (but hardly ever the shortest) is better.

Answer (score 5):

I personally would use a map for this:

```
public static String myFunc (String s) {
     Map<Character, String> map = new HashMap<>();
     map.put('a', "Awesome");
     map.put('b', "Badass");
     ...
     return map.getOrDefault(s.charAt(0), "Invalid Character, please try again");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to improve your development, maintencement and performance use the switch case operators, since that you are "stuck" in those inicial programming steps.

```
switch(int c) {
 case 97:
  ...
 case 98:
  ...
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

As someone else has already pointed out, your function needs a name, not just a return type and a parameter. Try something like 
`public static String stringMaker (String S) { }`
also, why are you converting to integers, when you could have c be a char? Also, just heads up, you can't convert upper case letters like this, because they have different ASCII codes.

Comment: This should be more of a comment than an answer

Comment: I would, but the reputation system doesn't allow me

Comment: Yeah, i wrote this quickly and ignored errors and the other parts of my code which is on a school computer. Thank you for the heads up though!